# Jquery mobile Collabsible Listview not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to do [remote autocomplete](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/) with [collapsible list view](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/).
.Its working perfectly for normal listview..but when i use collapsible list view its not working.please see the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/Q8dBH/8/

Below is my code

```
<div data-role="page" id="startseite">


    <!--<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">!-->

        <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="enter 3 or more alphabets...for ex : america " data-filter-theme="a"></ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

my javascript

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#startseite", function () {
    $(document).on("click", "li", function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).closest("ul").prev("form").find("input").val(text);    });
    $("#autocomplete").on("filterablebeforefilter", function (e, data) {
        var $ul = $(this),
            $input = $(data.input),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html("");
        if (value && value.length > 2) {
            $ul.html("<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>");
            $ul.listview("refresh");
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    q: $input.val()
                }
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                    html += "<li data-role='collapsible' data-iconpos='right' data-shadow='false' data-corners='false'><h2>Birds</h2>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                $ul.html(html);
                $ul.listview("refresh");
                $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8dBH/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Q8dBH/10/

Use:

```
$('#startseite').enhanceWithin();
```

Instead of:

```
$ul.listview("refresh");
$ul.trigger("updatelayout");
```

Basically pre jQuery Mobile 1.4 each widget had it own enhancement method while there were two content wide enhancement methods (unfortunately they were not always successful). jQuery Mobile 1.4 brought new function called **enhanceWithin()** which is used for content enhancement, specially if you are creating more then 1 dynamic widget. In your case you have 2 widgets, listview and collapsible so **listview("refresh")** will not be enough.

### Update:

If you want to remove a gap use this CSS:

```
.ui-listview > li h1, .ui-listview > li h2, .ui-listview > li h3, .ui-listview > li h4, .ui-listview > li h5, .ui-listview > li h6 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Or create everything inside a collapsible-set.

Comment: thanks gajotres, but did u see the collapsible list view ? there is gap between each field..how to make it look like http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-collapsible-item-indented/

Comment: thanks for enhanceWithin() ;) +1 ..but why list is not like http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-collapsible-item-indented/

Comment: hey my last request.... when user typing .. i need to show loading icon...please check http://jsfiddle.net/Q8dBH/11/  ..It shows loading icon only 1st time..why not other time ? can u please solve this..

Answer (score 0):

If the control is loaded with ajax you will have to use:

```
$(document).on('filterablebeforefilter','#autocomplete',function(e,data){
   ...
})
```